# OSError: [WinError 10049] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен

Tags: python, сокет

```
HOST = '236.6.7.8'
PORT = 6678
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind( (HOST, PORT) )
```

Comment: можете ли вы залить исправленный код?

Comment: self.MCAST_GRP = '236.6.7.8'
        self.MCAST_PORT = 6678
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind(('', self.MCAST_PORT))  # use MCAST_GRP instead of '' to listen only
                             # to MCAST_GRP, not all groups on MCAST_PORT
        mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(self.MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас специальный мультикастовый адрес. А с ним работать нужно правильно. Вначале нужно сделать бинд (это как раз Вы и начали делать), а потом подсоединится к мультикаст группе.

Если бы это  было на линуксе, то все ок. там так работатет. А вот на винде нужно подключаться на IN_ADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0), иначе будете получать указанную ошибку.

На хабре есть немного [больше деталей](https://habr.com/ru/post/141021/)